# Is it possible to set user input as variables?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it is possible to set user input as a variable..

My code is:

```
<input id="userBlank" type="text" value="Click" onclick="userInput();">
<div id="userInput"></div>

<script>
function userInput(){
userInput.innerHTML = userBlank.value
</script>
```

So basically, I want to how I can set userInput.value as a variable so I can use it to calculate other things. I tried putting var at the front but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Put you input inside of a form and get the value by using `getElementById`!

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="userBlank" type="text" value="Click" onclick="userInput();">
</form>
<script>
function userInput(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userBlank").value;
    alert(userInput);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using id in an element, use document.getElementById

```
<script>
function userInput(){
    var myValue = document.getElementById('userBlank').value ;
    document.getElementById('userInput').innerHTML = myValue ;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use function then you can do like this

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input id="userBlank" type="text" value="Click" onclick="userInput();">
</form>
<script>
function userInput(){
    var userInputVar = document.getElementById("userBlank").val();
    console.log(userInputVar)
    alert(userInputVar);
}
<script>
```